# Checkbox state needs to show or hide a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox that, when checked, will display a div. As expected, when it is unchecked, the div will be hidden.

I've got as far as the following code but I need a way to check if the checkbox itself is toggling from check to uncheck!

```
$(function(){
    if($('#guess_the_score').is(':checked')){
        $("#guess_score_show").toggle();
    }
});
```

The checkbox has an id of `guess_the_score`
The div to be displayed has an id of `guess_score_show`

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.change` event of `checkbox` and **show hide div** as shown :

```
$(function(){
  $('#guess_the_score').change(function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#guess_score_show").show();
     }
     else{ 
        $("#guess_score_show").hide(); 
     }
  }).change();  //trigger on page load
});
```

OR

```
$(function(){
  $('#guess_the_score').change(function(){
      $("#guess_score_show").toggle(this.checked);
  }).change();   //trigger on page load
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkm67t6x/1/)

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkm67t6x/2/)

Comment: Great answer, works just as expected. I was just typing in to ask what the change() did that you added to the end, thanks!

Comment: @Luke..it will trigger .change() event on page load also.

Comment: if you want to trigger `.change()` event when first time your page will load then you can use `.change()` in the end otherwise you can leave it...@Luke

Answer (score 4):

You should use `change()` event, The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes.

Use

```
$(function() {
    $('#guess_the_score').change(function() {
        $("#guess_score_show").toggle(this.checked);
    }).change(); //Trigger on page load
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#guess_the_score').on('change', function() {
    $("#guess_score_show").toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
#guess_score_show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Toggle Score
<input id="guess_the_score" type="checkbox" />
<br>
<div id="guess_score_show">Score: 10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#guess_the_score').click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#guess_score_show").show();
    } else {
        $("#guess_score_show").hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i send it

Comment: I checked my mail and i'll send the finalized version before EOD.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function(){
  $('#guess_the_score').change(function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#guess_score_show").show();
     }
     else{ 
        $("#guess_score_show").hide(); 
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery  "Change" event you can also use

```
$('#guess_the_score').change(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
                $("#guess_score_show").show();
    }else
        {
                    $("#guess_score_show").hide();
        }
});
```

or
you can also use "On " event

```
 $('#guess_the_score').on('change',function(){

        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
                    $("#guess_score_show").show();
        }else
            {
                        $("#guess_score_show").hide();
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) accepts a boolean value indicating whether to show or hide the elements.
So you can do like this:

```
$('#guess_the_score').change(function(){
   $('#theDiv').toggle($('#guess_the_score').is(':checked'));
});
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hr32efbt/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Text Test</title>
  <style>

  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" id="guess_the_score"/><span>Hide/show score</span>
    <div id="guess_score_show">Score is 500</div>
    

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#guess_the_score').change(function () {
                $("#guess_score_show").toggle(this.checked);
            }).change();
        });
        
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```